# Getting error on my dashboard after rollback SQL

Tags: magento-1.9, database, admin-panel, fatal-error

Getting error on my dashboard after rollback SQL 
[image]

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on boolean in /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Mage_Captcha_Block_Captcha extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
/**
 * Renders captcha HTML (if required)
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockPath =   Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($this->getFormId()->getBlockName());
```

Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($this->getFormId()) should return a block instance but because of some reasons it is not returning the block instance. try clearing cache. and also check the permissions of your var folder. also check your logs may be you can get some helpful information there.
 @Rajiv please share your email id as i could not find email id on your profile(Let's hope its not against the community rules).

Comment: @Rajiv. your issue resolved ???

Answer (score 0):

The root of the error is that the block wasn't found so `Mage::getBlock` is returning false instead of an instance of a block.  Did you clear your cache after rolling back?  Did you also roll back the code base or just the SQL?

Comment: I just rollback SQL only

Comment: Typically if you're rolling back the SQL you should be rolling ack the code as well.  Either way, this is a code issue, not a database issue.